# How to test console command with mocked functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I'm trying to make tests for my console script.

```js
# src/functions.ts

const fn1 = () => console.log('fn1');
const fn2 = () => console.log('fn2');
const fnErr = () => console.log('fnErr');
```

```js
# index.ts

import { fn1, fn2, fnErr } from './src/functions';

(() => {
  try {
    fn1();
    fn2();
  } catch {
    fnErr();
  }
})();
```

And tests which have to cover this code

```js
# index.test.ts

import { execSync } from 'child_process';
import { fn1, fn2, fnErr } from './src/functions';

jest.mock('./src/functions', () => ({
  fn1: jest.fn(),
  fn2: jest.fn(),
  fnErr: jest.fn(),
}))

describe('Command line execution', () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it('should correctly execute from command line', () => {
    const mockVal1 = 'Mocked fn1 called';
    const mockVal2 = 'Mocked fn2 called';
    const mockErr = 'Mocked fnErr called';
    (fn1 as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() => {
      console.log(mockVal1);
    });

    (fn2 as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() => {
      console.log(mockVal2);
    });

    (fnErr as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() => {
      console.log(mockErr);
    });

    const output = execSync('ts-node index.ts', { encoding: 'utf8', stdio: 'pipe' });

    expect(output).toBe(`\n${mockVal1}\n${mockVal2}`);
    expect(fn1).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(fn2).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(fnErr).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

When I'm trying to run this test, I got an error because functions weren't mocked.

Obviously, I do it wrong. Mocks don't work with executable scripts.

But is there some way how to test the only one script without (using mock implementation) side functions?

Comment: What did you do wrong?

Comment: This test is incorrect: it covers not only the script but also fn1 and fn2 implementations. Mocks don't work and when I'm trying to run the test, I'm getting base implementation these functions

Comment: You're exec-ing a script; that spins up a completely new environment. The script as-is is unnecessarily difficult to test. Export a function you can call.

Comment: I have suggested to hear something like this but hoped there is some way how to do it. Thanks